# Why is my external class not found during execution of my Spring REST program?

Tags: java, spring, maven

Below I describe my issue.

**Description**
I do a program using Spring REST interface. Normally I use the IDE Eclipse to code, build and generate a jar to execute.
But now I want to use Maven, I can build and generate jar (normal or executable) but when executing the jar I got problem..

**Problem**
When executing the jar and executing a REST path I get the fault:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[stocks-rest-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT
```

It seems that a class cannot be found but class from another project from me is in the exported jar in m2 with correct version.

Code:

```
/**
 * Version 1.0.2
 */
package Rest;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import Enums.Market;
import Enums.REA_Stock_State;
import Enums.Stock_State;
import myExceptions.ElementSizeException;
import REA.REAMain;
import REA.REAStock;
import Stocks.Logger;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class StocksRestApi 
{
    private Logger iLogger = null; 
    
    public StocksRestApi()
    {
        iLogger = new Logger();   
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SpringApplication.run(StocksRestApi.class, args);
    }
    
    @GetMapping(value="/rea")
    public String rea() throws HeadlessException, MalformedURLException, IOException, AWTException, InterruptedException, UnsupportedFlavorException, IllegalClassFormatException, ElementSizeException 
    {
        List<REAStock> stocks = REAMain.doAnalyze(true, Market.LARGE_CAP_STHLM_KEYFIGURE, REA_Stock_State.REA_ANALYZE, Stock_State.UNKNOWN, iLogger); 
        String allStocks = ""; 
    
        for(int index = 0; index < stocks.size(); index++)
        {
             allStocks += index + 1 + ". " + stocks.get(index).getName() + " "; 
             if(index < 20)
             {
                 allStocks += "<br>"; 
             }
             if(index == 19)
             {
                 allStocks += "------------------------------<br>"; 
             }
         }
        return allStocks;
    }
}
```

My POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    
    <!-- My project -->
    <groupId>tobbe</groupId>
    <artifactId>stocks-rest</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    
    <!-- My projects -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>tobbe</groupId>
        <artifactId>Stocks_Backend</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>tobbe</groupId>
        <artifactId>Other</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

**Question**
Why is class not found during execution of jar?

Comment: it mostly always has something to do with the package naming, are you invoking with import Rest.StockRestAPI?

Comment: StocksRestApi is the class where main method exist and is in the project which generates the jar (only this class in this project). 
Order: StocksRestApi.java (in project Stocks_Rest)-> REAMain.java (in another project named Stock_Backend)-> StocksFromDI.java with packetname: Stocks (in project Stock_Backend but class not found, the exception is thrown). 
Maybe change packetname: Stocks?

Comment: try merging them into one project...i dont know